# coarse-grain parallelization with python using multicore processors

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multicore

I have a python program, at a point it calls an external program (foo). This external program needs to be run several times. The exact number of times (num_pros) is variable and depends on the input.
Because this external program is by far the most time consuming part of my Python program I would like to take advantage of multiple cores processors to run several instances of the external program at the same time.

I came with the following solution that take into account that num_pros is unknown a priori and that the solution should be adaptable to any number of cores.

```
cores=2
proc_list=[]
for i in range(0,num_pros):
    proc=Popen(['foo'], stdin=PIPE)
    proc_list.append(proc)
    if i%cores == cores-1: 
        for process in proc_list:
            process.wait()
```

I have two questions:

There is a better (more efficient or pythonic) solution?

This code reduce the execution time only when the cores are real. Is this a hardware issue? Or something that could be fixed using python?

To clarify the second question let me provide an example.
In my notebook (running linux) the comnand 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l' indicates the existence of 4 processor if I use cores=2 in my code I get the results in half the time (as expected), but when using cores=3 or cores=4 I get the same performance that when using cores=2. I have an Intel core I3 (2 cores and 4 threads) hence I guess that the problem is that only 2 cores are real (I test the code in other computer/processor I get the same result only real cores seems to be useful).

Comment: i don't really understand the modulo calculation and waiting logic.  if you simply want to run a variable number of processes, but never have more than n_core processes running at once, the best approach is to use a process pool from multiprocessng http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: @andrew if cores=2 the modulo calculation will be true every two steps if cores=3 every three steps, etc. i.e. it will run as many processes as processor available and then wait until they have finished... May be that exactly what pool does I am going to check your link.

Comment: the pool will be more efficient if they take different lengths of time (ps in general you do get *some* gain from hyperthreading, so something seems odd with what you are describing).

Comment: the processes take almost the same time. I try to use Pool but I did not get better results (in fact they were worst). I have to check if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `multiprocessing` is more intended for the case where the work you want to farm out is in python, not a totally different process.  It's all about using `fork` and passing stuff from python process to python process, so I don't think it will work for you.

In your current implementation, once the max number of subprocesses is spawned, your code is blocking the spawning of new subprocesses until *all* the current batch of processes complete because `Popen.wait()` blocks until *that specific* subprocess completes.

I think what you want is [`os.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.wait).  I've done something [very similar](https://gitorious.org/rpatterson-splitpipe/rpatterson-splitpipe/blobs/master/rpatterson/splitpipe/__init__.py#line74) by keeping a mapping of my `subprocess.Popen` instances mapped by pid.  Just spin up your max number of  subprocesses and then let `os.wait()` tell you when one of them finishes.  `os.wait()` will give you the pid of whatever `Popen` instances completes next and you can use that to do any remaining cleanup for *that* subprocess.  Then you let your code spin up the next subprocess.

Comment: I think you are right about multiprocessing I tried to do something with Pool and I get poorer performance than with my own code (but of course maybe I am doing something wrong). Which will be the advantage of  using os.wait() over my implementation? I believe that the idea of the subprocess module (that I use) was to replace some of the functions in the os module.

Comment: Read the docs for `os.wait`, look at the example code I linked to and tell me what you don't understand.

Comment: I just don´t get why I should use os.wait() over Popen.wait(). Your code and my code seems very similar and I don´t get the advantage of one over the other... May be my code will be easier to read/understand if I change the `if i%cores == cores-1:` stament for a `if len(proc_list) == cores:` (of course I should make a new assignment for proc_list).
 )

Comment: Now that I understand what's confusing you, I've clarified my answer, see above.

Comment: Ok thanks!!! I realize that my code have the problem you mention (my code  blocks the spawning of new subprocesses until all the current batch of processes are completed)... I did not care to much because each process take almost the same amount of time... But I understand that your implementation is more general and it will indeed perform better than mine. I will adapt my code. BTW, any idea about the second part of my question? :-)

Comment: Validate your assumptions.  :-)  Try fixing the code as I suggest then redo your timing tests.  If you still don't see any improvement with the number of processes equal to the number of hyperthreads then you need to include more details, specifically how you're testing the timing and what the subprocesses are doing.  Whether or not the subprocesses can take effective advantage of hyperthreads has everything to do with *what* those processes are.

Comment: the fixed code is ~5% faster than the old code... (as I said  all the process takes almost the same time to finish). The external program (foo) is actually a program written in FORTRAN. According to your last comments and some googling it seems that there is nothing I can do here with the python code... may be I should take a look at the FORTRAN code... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: take an N-cores system, do some benchmarking runs to establish how many processes your app needs to perform at maximum efficiency. It will probably be around N, N+1 or N+2 processes (eg. for the usual software build `make` runs the docs often suggests setting -j to N+1). Then for the production runs just ask the user or the operating system for the number of *physical cores* (not threads) and spawn your N or N+1 or whatever processes.

More convoluted, cool, and not necessarily better way: if you can measure the throughput of completed units of work, you can try to adjust the number of processes on the fly without even knowing/detecting the number of cpu/cores/threads - something like TCP window size if you like. Start with a target of 2 processes, when the first ends up measure throughput and go target+=1 (ie, bring the total to 3 processes). Measure, rinse, repeat. Keep incrementing as long as the total throughput keeps going up, and decrement it when it goes down. Throw some hysteresis in the mix and be sure to configure a sane upper limit.

Regarding your notebook example, yes that's a multithreaded CPU, multiple threads will benefit some workloads more than others, yours is one that doesn't benefit from it :)